# Power Bi linked with Twitter

Tags: twitter, powerbi

Im quite new using Power Bi and im also not a programmer, so im facing some problems with the integration between Twitter and Power Bi.
I found this code (below) to integrate these two programs, but it has a limit of 100 rows. To increase this, i need to work with pagination (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/general/guides/pagination).
However, as i said, my knowledge in this field is almost 0!
Does anyone knows what i need to change in this code?
Tks in advance!

http://chris.koester.io/index.php/2015/07/16/get-data-from-twitter-api-with-power-query/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any code for this.
The easier solution is connecting twitter to power bi using a third-party connector.which should be seemlingsly easy.
But you can also create an app following this link https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/getting-access-to-the-twitter-api
and after use the API URL and secret key in Get data -> From web and add it in the box that appears